# Negative Infinity AIC and BIC

Tags: distributions, aic, gamma-distribution, bic

I was trying to compare best fit model for monthly precipitation data sets and negative and positive infinity (-inf and inf) as values have showed up for both AIC and BIC tests. Can anyone tell me what that means? I am using it to compare which dataset has good fit for gamma distribution.

Comment: AIC and BIC are information criteria, not tests.

Answer (score 2):

It shows that something is wrong.

- AIC is defined as $2k - 2\log \hat L$, so it would be infinite when the likelihood $\hat L$ is zero since $\log(0) = -\infty$. This would happen if the data has probability of zero or probability density of zero under the model. In such a case, your model is not appropriate for the data, since the data is considered to be impossible by the model.
- Another possibility are numerical errors or bug in your code, so you need to do standard debugging.